# PHP code for VOIP notification not working

Tags: php, ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, voip

We are using VOIP notification in our iOS app for call notification.. it’s working perfectly somedays ago.. now it’s not working from server side.. by checking below command in Terminal it works. Please help us founding php code similar to the terminal command below..

Command Used in Terminal

```
curl -v -d '{"aps":{"data":{"apiKey":"","call_type":"2","login_id":"457","session_id":"","channel_msg_type":"","token":"","user_name":"","receiver_login_id":"","channelid":""}}}' --http2 --cert VOIP.pem:12345678 https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/bd68469039729200d7580382a0bfdc9542c93ebab48a49290822ad112267361455
```

PHP Code( from https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification#use-this-sendsilenpushphp-file )

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):


$deviceToken = '1234567890123456789';
//


// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ProjectName';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first silent push notification!';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PemFileName.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
//  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body

$body['aps'] = array(
'content-available'=> 1,
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge' => 0,
);



// Encode the payload as JSON

$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: It was working, now it's not. Something has changed in data or code. What?

Comment: no changes in data and code.